# filter slugs (url) with regex

Tags: regex

*Im new to regex so I may have made some stupid error*

### goal:

I am looking for a regex which:

1. matches: `/saj/`
2. fails at: `/asdf/adsf/`

### context:

For my markdown site built with gatsby I need to filter al submenus (/x/) from subpages (/x/x/).

### my attempts:

- `(\/.*?\/)`

  - https://regexr.com/5sgjt
- `/(\/.*?)(?!\/{2,})/`

  - https://regexr.com/5sgk3

Comment: Like this? `^\/[^\/]+\/$` https://regex101.com/r/mbFqTt/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you thats it! If you want i could accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this pattern `(\/.*?\/)` will get a partial match, but it would also match `//` as the quantifier is optional. Note that you also don't need the capture group.

Using this pattern `(\/.*?)(?!\/{2,})` captures a single `/` followed by as least as possible chars asserting not 2 or more `/` at the right.

---

You can match the whole line using anchors and match at least a single char other than `/` in between using a negated character class `[^\/]+`

```
^\/[^\/]+\/$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbFqTt/1)